# Unterminated object when converting a String to JSON

Tags: java, android, escaping, json

I am working with Android Studio, andI have a string variable, called sResponse (below). According to the debugger, it holds the following value:

```
 {
    "responseData": {
    "emotion":"",
    "lastinput":{actionResult={"value":{"label":"green","key":"1"},"result":"success","action":"displayClickableList"},
    "answer":"Sorry, I did not understand.",
    "link": {
    "href":"",
    "target":""
    },
    "extraData": {

    },
    "responseSession": {
    "id":"c4a5ef257851a991eb32c69132c9",
    "transaction":"4"
    },
    "responseDetails": "null",
    "responseStatus": "200",
    "applicationUrl": "http://noki-dev.cloud.com:90/moto-1/"
    }
    }
```

When I try to initialize a JSONObject with it with in this way:

```
jResponse=new JSONObject(sResponse);
```

...The following exception rises in my Logcat:

```
>>>>>>>>>Thread EXCEPTION1: Response with invalid JSON format: , FrontendActivity.java L:421 ***** *org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 502 of : sResponse
```

I suspect that those // in the URL are causing trouble. I am no expert in escaping JSON Characters. How can I obtain a valid JSONObject from the previous string? What trouble can you spot in my approach?

Comment: you have improper json please correct `actionResult=` object in your json response

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake @NambiNarayanan, the value comes from a backed (hardcoded perhaps?), but please don't downvote!

Comment: ok i removed my vote casting,but check your question before posting it in the future.

Comment: @Josh you should accept correct answer if its useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem caused because of `=` sign near by `actionResult` as well as `actionResult` not surrounded with double quotes and you didn't close json string properly.

Replace Json String With:

```
{
    "responseData": {
    "emotion":"",
    "lastinput":{"actionResult":{"value":{"label":"green","key":"1"},"result":"success","action":"displayClickableList"},
    "answer":"Sorry, I did not understand.",
    "link": {
    "href":"",
    "target":""
    },
    "extraData": {

    },
    "responseSession": {
    "id":"c4a5ef257851a991eb32c69132c9",
    "transaction":"4"
    },
    "responseDetails": "null",
    "responseStatus": "200",
    "applicationUrl": "http://noki-dev.cloud.com:90/role-va-1/"
    }
    }
}
```

and add `}` at the end of the string.

You can track the error using following online tool:

http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Thanks, you where right, I had been struggling a couple of hours and my thick eyes just would not see the mistake!! It comes from a backend though.

Answer (score 1):

You missed last closing curly at the end of the response. 
Just add `}` on last line.

Corrected json Response

```
{
  "responseData": {
    "emotion": "",
    "lastinput": {
      actionResult: {
        "value": {
          "label": "green",
          "key": "1"
        },
        "result": "success",
        "action": "displayClickableList"
      },
      "answer": "Sorry, I did not understand.",
      "link": {
        "href": "",
        "target": ""
      },
      "extraData": {

      },
      "responseSession": {
        "id": "c4a5ef257851a991eb32c69132c9",
        "transaction": "4"
      },
      "responseDetails": "null",
      "responseStatus": "200",
      "applicationUrl": "http://noki-dev.cloud.com:90/moto-1/"
    }
  }
}
```